# $\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_2]$ of permutation on $9$ elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, expectation

We arrange $9$ balls numbered $1,\dots,9$ in a row randomly (a permutation). Let $X_i$ an indicator to the ball in the $i$ position is less than the ball in the $i+1$.

> Prove $\mathbb{E}[X_2|X_1]=\frac{1}{3}(2-X_1)$

I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. On the left-hand side, $X_2$ is free and $X_1$ is bound, not the other way around. Also, $i\lt i+1$ is trivially true. You probably mean something like $\pi(i)\lt\pi(i+1)$?

Comment: @joriki You are right. I have fixed that.

Comment: You've fixed the first part. The problem that $i\lt i+1$ is trivially true remains.

Comment: @joriki Fixed it again. Hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the balls in positions $4$ to $9$. There are $3!=6$ different rankings of the balls in positions $1$ to $3$, and they're equiprobable by symmetry. Then it's just a matter of counting cases.

Comment: Got it. So I get $\mathbb{P}[X_2|X_1=1]=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\mathbb{P}[X_2|X_1=0]=\frac{2}{3}$ and I'm done. I did it by writing all the possible permutation on 6 elements and then counting. I was wondering if there's more elegant way.

Comment: @GalushBalush: Where it says $\mathbb P$ you mean $\mathbb E$. You should take more care in writing things! :-)

Comment: @GalushBalush: I'm not sure whether you'd consider this more elegant: When you order the first three balls by their numbers, if you know which side of the second ball the first ball is on, there are two ways to arrange the third ball on the same side and only one to arrange it on the other side.

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{P}$ and  $\mathbb{E}$ are equivalent in that case. That's why I took the liberty to use $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: @GalushBalush: What's equivalent is $\mathbb E[X_2]$ and $\mathbb P[X_2=1]$. Just $\mathbb P[X_2]$ makes no sense.

Comment: @GalushBalush The notation you want is $\mathbb E(X_2\mid X_1) ~{= \mathbb P(X_2{=}1\mid X_1{=}1)~\mathbf 1_{X_1=1}+\mathbb P(X_2{=}1\mid X_1{=}0)~\mathbf 1_{X_1=0}\\=\tfrac 13~ X_1+\tfrac 23~(1-X_1)\\=\tfrac 13(2-X_1)}$